# Zendesk API Jquery AJAX JSONP Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, zendesk

I'm trying to use jquery ajax to get my Zendesk Help Center data. With the following code, I keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Here is my JS.

```
var configMap = {
  api_base : 'https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: configMap.api_base + 'categories.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

JSFIDDLE 
http://jsfiddle.net/cmu5p6ta/

Comment: I don't get that error when I run it. Can you create a fiddle showing this happening?

Comment: Added jsfiddle link.

Comment: Did you create that json file or was it created by a 3rd party?

Comment: That json file is from the Zendesk API. https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/help_center/introduction

Comment: I don't think you can do it with an ajax/JSONP request then. The format is not what is expected by a JSONP request. You're probably going to have to do it with a server-side request. So what you can do is make an ajax request to a file (say a PHP file) on your own server, that then makes a curl request to zendesk and returns the result to your ajax function.

Comment: token mean wrong code language, look http://prntscr.com/9tc8iu is not use comma of end and just remove.